# Getting value from SimpleXMLElement field

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, docusignapi

So here's my problem: I have an XML file that I've loaded into SimpleXML.

```
<EnvelopeStatus>
    <RecipientStatuses>
      <RecipientStatus>
        <FormData>
          <xfdf>
            <fields>
              <field name="ubi_num">
                <value>2222</value>
              </field>
              <field name="lic_num">
                <value>1111</value>
              </field>
              <field name="tra_nam">
                <value>Flakey</value>
              </field>
            </fields>
```

I'm trying to access the fields within FormData. This is the last SimpleXML call that I've tried:

```
$xml->EnvelopeStatus->RecipientStatuses->RecipientStatus->FormData->xfdf->fields->field['ubi_num']
```

Nothing has worked when trying to get to a specific field. Can somebody please point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `fields` contains several `field` elements that you'll need to loop over, or identify by index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I solved my problem: I created some empty variables to hold my data.

```
$ubinum = "";
$licnum = "";
$tranam = "";
```

I then started my foreach loop using a switch statement.

```
foreach ($xml->EnvelopeStatus->RecipientStatuses->RecipientStatus->FormData->xfdf->fields->field as $xmlfield) {
  // Loop over the custom field nodes and read the name of each
  switch ($xmlfield->attributes()->name) {
    // Load a variable on each matching name attribute
    // or do whatever you need with them.
    case "ubi_num":
      $ubinum = $xmlfield->value;
      break;
    case "lic_num":
      $licnum = $xmlfield->value;
      break;
    case "tra_nam":
      $tranam = $xmlfield->value;
      break;
  }

}
```

I then setup my array with the variables and other data needed and then used fopen and fwrite to create my CSV file.

```
$csvarr = array($ubinum, $licnum, $tranam, $xml->EnvelopeStatus->Signed, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . $xml->EnvelopeStatus->EnvelopeID . "/" . $xml->EnvelopeStatus->DocumentStatuses->DocumentStatus->Name . ".pdf");
$csvfiles = $xml->EnvelopeStatus->EnvelopeID . "/" . $xml->EnvelopeStatus->EnvelopeID . '.csv';
$file = fopen($csvfiles,"w");
fputcsv($file, $csvarr, '|');

fclose($file);
```

I'm glad it works because it was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Your `fields` element contains many other elements. To access them and extract the required result, you can simply loop over the [`children()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) pseudo-array, like so:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);    
$children = $xml->RecipientStatuses->RecipientStatus->FormData->xfdf->fields->children();

foreach ($children as $child) {
  echo $child->value . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2222
1111
Flakey
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/ugCxgLMh)

Documentation: [`children()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) method

Comment: Is there a better way of turning my file into a string? I don't have access to the XML files since they are coming from third party software. I'm also writing this to a CSV file and pulling in some other fields from other entry points of the XML.

Comment: @duckie715: Sure, yes. It's possible to load XML from a URL. Use [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_file) instead.